# how to add a member variable to a python object

Tags: python, attributeerror

```py
class Empty:
    pass

a = Empty()
a.m = 1
```

the above code works well and there is no error.

```py
a = object()
a.m = 1 # it throws AttributeError
```

but this code throws an exception.

`AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'm'`

What is the difference?

I just want an empty object and add some variable to it.

How can I do that? Should I make an empty class?